# Android Dialer in the Background

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to call the `Intent.ACTION_CALL` in the background ?

I want my application to call but I don't want it to put in the background, I want it to stay in the foreground while it is calling.

Comment: Call cannot be done in the background, but you can invoke your app to the foreground after a second or two after the call has been made.

Comment: How can I call again my previous activity to the foreground after calling the Intent.ACTION_CALL?

Comment: It can be done, i saw an app that call in the background, i just see on the top the symbol of the dialer

Answer (score 0):

The Intent.ACTION_CALL will call the default Android Phone activity and call the number you provided. If you want your App to be in the foreground, which i take to understanding you are builder your own calling app, you will have to implement the Calling part yourself.

Otherwise you can launch your activity with say a 5 seconds delay if you just want to show the user a context of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Samarth. Can I ask one more question? 

How to call back my previous activity once I launched the Intent.ACTION_CALL?

Comment: call startActivity with a 5 sec delay for your activity after you call startActivity on the Intent.Action_Call. Or Listen to Phone State events and launch your activity when the phone starts Dialling out.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke your activity after making a call using this,

```
package com.sdi.androidcall;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button call;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call);

        final PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
        final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,
                                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                    }
                }, 10000);

            }
        });
    }


    private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        boolean flag = true;

        String LOG_TAG = "Call TEST";

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "number: " + incomingNumber);

            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

                // invoking activity
                if (flag) {
                    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                                    getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    System.out.println("flagged retrieving app");
                    flag = false;

                }

            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

            }
        }
    }

}
```

The activity will be called after a delay of 10 seconds here using `PhoneStateListener`

You need to specify the intent permissions in the mainfest as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Try it, let me know if worked.